# Como ordenar array por nome e remover valores negativos?

Tags: php

Eu preciso ordenar um array por nome, e remover os valores negativos.
A ordenação eu consegui fazer usando o método `sort`. Mas, como eu removo os valores negativos? Existe alguma função nativa?

```
$data = [
    [
        'name'  => 'XXX003',
        'value' => -55
    ],
    [
        'name'  => 'XXX002',
        'value' => 4445
    ],
    [
        'name'  => 'XXX001',
        'value' => 666
    ],
    [
        'name'  => 'XXX004',
        'value' => -88
    ]
];

sort($data);

print_r($data);
```

Comment: tem uma resposta sobre remover valores negativos de um `array` usando a função `array_filter` no StackOverflow em inglês:


 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101613/filter-out-negative-integers-from-an-array-php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adaptando a resposta do [StakOverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101613/filter-out-negative-integers-from-an-array-php) para o seu código de exemplo, ficara algo como isso:

```
<?php


$data = [
    [
        'name'  => 'XXX003',
        'value' => -55
    ],
    [
        'name'  => 'XXX002',
        'value' => 4445
    ],
    [
        'name'  => 'XXX001',
        'value' => 666
    ],
    [
        'name'  => 'XXX004',
        'value' => -88
    ]
];


$apenasPositivos = array_filter($data, function($value){
    return $value['value'] > 0;
});

print_r($apenasPositivos);
```